# Google Analytics API | Handling Quota limits of 100 req per 100 seconds

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, quota

So far I have more than 200 google analytic accounts to pull information. I've tested my solution with a restrict number of accounts (only 10). 
Once I put all the account ids in my logic it gives me errors of **quota limit 100 requests per 100 seconds**.

```
 foreach (var viewID in _viewIds)
 {
     foreach (var dateRange in dateRanges)
     {
         tTaskList.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
         {
            try
            {  var tReports = await gc.PostAsyncTask(url, reportRequest);

                foreach (var report in tReports.reports)
                {
                    if (report != null)
                    {
                    //All report logic here
                    //(...)

                        bool hasNextPage = false;
                        do
                        {
                            //All pagination logic here
                            //(...)
                        }while(hasNextPage);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Write in Log
                var ex_message = Common.Utils.GetExceptionMessage(ex);
                Logger.WriteConsoleLog(ex_message.MessageString, (int)Logger.Logs.ERROR, APIName, RequestID);
            }        
         })
         ); //end add task
     }
 }
```

How can I control the number of requests? To avoid getting these errors?

Answer (score -1):

> quota limit 100 requests per 100 seconds.

Its basically flood protection you are going to fast.  You can max make 100 requests with in 100 seconds.   What you can do and probably the simplest solution would be to [Implementing Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors#backoff)

I went a step further in my application though.  I created a request que (max 100 items in it).  I log the time I make a request down to the millisecond.  Before I send a request i check the time difference between the first and the last item in the que if its more then say 95 seconds i pause it for the difference.   This has not completely stopped me from getting these errors but its has reduced them drastically.

Comment: So, we can say, if I use these queue solution plus the explonential backoff, I could manage to avoid these errors? Lets say I reduce them drastically, but still have one or another error, I can catch them and do the exponential backoff and retry again.

Comment: Thats actually what i do as well if i do get one i just retry it.    I just didnt like that i was getting so many so i added the Que idea to reduce them further.   Google actually just recommends that you implement back off.  You dont have to add the que it just depends if your like me and dont like seeing the errors on the report in developer console.